# Linear Temporal Logic equvalences

Tags: logic, temporal, automata-theory

for an LTL formula `FG p & FG q` I want to poof or reject that it is equivalent to  `F (G p & Gq)`. I think by distribution law we can write `F(Gp&Gq)` as `FG(p&q)`. can we also say `FG p & FG q = FG(p&q)` ?

Answer (score 1):

This only works in your particular case, because `p` and `q` are atomic propositions. Generally, it can be difficult to decide which formulae allow distribution of operators and which don't (cf. Samer & Veith: On the Distributivity of LTL Specifications, 2010). Another way you could prove your particular claim is via a Buechi automaton, which in all three cases looks as follows (cf. [http://www.lsv.fr/~gastin/ltl2ba/index.php](http://www.lsv.fr/%7Egastin/ltl2ba/index.php)). Generally, equivalence of LTL formulae is PSpace-complete, so often not so easily answerable without Buechi automata.

[image]